# How to install parted 3.2?

Tags: centos, gparted, parted

I need to resize one of my disks and a lot of information leads to the `resize` function from parted. But that's removed from parted in version 3.1. And 3.2 is just released. But when I do:

```
yum parted
```

I get version 3.1.

To install 3.2 there's this [guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.0/postlfs/parted.html) but it's a bit too technical for me and I can't figure out what to do.

Any tips on how  to update/install parted 3,2?

Answer (score 2):

To build a CentOS 7 rpm for parted 3.2, please follow these instructions:

- Set up an RPM build environment on a CentOS 7 machine as per https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment
- Login to that machine as a non-privileged user and cd to your RPM build environment.
- Get the Fedora 29 source RPM package (SRPM) for parted 3.2 by running `wget https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/parted-3.2-32.fc29.i686.rpm`
- Install the SRPM. Note that you do NOT use sudo for this one: `rpm -Uvh parted-3.2-32.fc29.i686.rpm`
- This particular SRPM requires dependencies that may or may not be present on your build machine. To be sure you meet the requirements, do: `sudo yum install e2fsprogs-devel readline-devel ncurses-devel texinfo device-mapper-devel libuuid-devel libblkid-devel dosfstools perl-Digest-CRC bc gperf`
- Then, rebuild the RPM for CentOS: `rpmbuild --rebuild parted-3.2-32.fc29.i686.rpm`
- It takes a while, but eventually the freshly built RPM is available in `<build root>/RPMS`
- Copy the RPM to the target machine and install: `sudo yum install parted-3.2-32.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: error: Failed dependencies:
        libreadline.so.8()(64bit) is needed by parted-3.3-1.fc32.x86_64
        libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) is needed by parted-3.3-1.fc32.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by parted-3.3-1.fc32.x86_64

Comment: ^That is with the very latest CentOS 7, running WHM/cPanel, and updated to the latest everything. You are also showing a file name disconnect between what you `wget` and what you `rpm -Uvh` in the very next bullet point.